# How to debug stack overflow in long if/else tree with many small static arrays

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

I'm trying to compile and run a c++ project that someone else wrote. This works in MacOS and linux but fails with a stack overflow on Windows using MS Visual Studio 2022. The problem is in a huge function that has thousands upon thousands of cases in an if-else tree where the inner nestings have assorted multi-dimensional static arrays. For example, something like this, but 4500 lines long:

```
void foo(int mode) {
  if (mode == 0) {
    int vals[2][5];
    ...
  }
  else if (mode == 1) {
    int vals[3][6][2];
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

How would typical compilers such as gcc and MS Visual Studio allocate stack space for this type of code pattern?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/f-set-stack-size?view=msvc-170

Comment: The answer to 1 (and subsequently 2-3) is that the compiler is free to optimise the code however it sees fit. That it creates a stack overflow in the process is astonishing, but then again, MSVC tends to do odd things. The answer to 4 is likely to write a small script to export the branches into individual functions. Alternatively, you could put all arrays into a `std::variant` but that will require some code rewrites.

Comment: Furthermore, I'd recommend running the noncrashing version (e.g. the GNU/Linux build) through valgrind or ASAN to make sure that there isn't a different (legitimate) source for the stack overflow.

Comment: Windows has a 1MB stack by default, Linux and macos use 8MB. Are you building the code in debug or release mode? I've seen some pretty bad code in my time but 4.5K lines in a single function has to be a record

Comment: if all else fails, you can move each of those `mode` isolations into their own stack frame (e.g. their own function). It would probably be much easier to manage and understand as a bonus.

Comment: Unless the code in a case is utterly trivial, write a function and call it.

Comment: VS does indeed seem to allocate separate stack space for each array in debug mode, I'd be surprised if it did the same in release mode (I haven't tested as I'd have to write something that doesn't get optimised away and you haven't provided a [mre])

Comment: I am really curious to find out how a person can think this is the best way to write such a function....Is still in your company? can you ask him/her?

Comment: _The problem is in a huge function that has thousands upon thousands of cases in an if-else tree_ I think you've put your finger on it there.

Comment: I'm trying to help someone build an open source project on Windows. I don't have another build to compare against or anywhere I can run it. The file itself is 22K lines of such functions, and I'm not willing to put in that much effort to rewrite it into a different style. I've provided feedback to the owner. I was creating a debug build in VS because I was expecting it wouldn't work and I would have to debug it. I'll try a release build. I mostly wanted to understand what was going on since I've never run into this problem before. Thanks!

Comment: Update: Switching from a Debug to a Release build didn't fix it. But going into the linker settings and increasing the stack size to 8MB did fix it.

Answer (score 2):

When compiling without optimisations enabled Visual Studio seems to allocate separate stack space for each of your variables (this isn't unreasonable, it makes debugging much easier if one variable doesn't suddenly change into another as you step though a function). When compiling in release mode it does optimise the unused arrays and allocate only the required stack space.

GCC does seem to not allocate separate stack space for each array even without optimisations enabled. Additionally the default stack size on macos and Linux is generally 8MB whereas on Windows it is usually 1MB.

The easiest solution to your problem is therefore probably to enable compiler optimisations. The better solution would be to refactor your code to be structured better.

For reference this is the code I used for testing:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int mode) {
  if (mode == 1)
  {
    int foo[200'000];
    std::cout << foo[mode];
  }
  else if (mode == 2)
  {
    int foo[200'000];
    std::cout << foo[mode + 2];
  }
  else if (mode == 3)
  {
    int foo[200'000];
    std::cout << foo[mode + 3];
  }
}

int main()
{
  int mode;
  std::cin >> mode;
  foo(mode);
}
```

In debug mode Visual Studio only allows 80,000 elements (80,000 * 4 (`sizeof(int)`) * 3 ~= 960kB).

In release mode it allows 200,000 elements (200,000 * 4 ~= 800kB).

[GCC on Linux](https://godbolt.org/z/orK8o7bhd) allows 2,000,000 elements (2,000,000 * 4 ~= 8MB).

Answer (score 1):

### Switch & Static

My quick suggestion is to use `switch` and `static`:

```
void Bar(const int mode)
{
    switch (mode)
    {
        case 0:  
        {
            static int vals[2][5];
            //...
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Using the `static` keyword moves the allocation to another memory segment that usually has more capacity than the local (stack) area.  A side effect is that all these array allocations will exist, whether the code goes through the case or not.

### Table of Function Pointers

Another method is to use a table of `<mode, function-pointer>`.  You could also use `std::map`.

```
typedef void (*Function_Pointer)();
void Do_Mode_0();
void Foo(const int mode)
{
    static std::map<int, Function_Pointer> delegation_table;
    static bool is_initialized = false;
    if (!is_initialized)
    {
        is_initialized = true;
        delegation_table[0] = Do_Mode_0;
        //...
    }
    // Execute the function
    Function_Pointer p_function = delegation_table[mode];
    (*p_function)(); // Execute the function associated with the mode.
}
```

This will make your function (with all the cases) a lot smaller.  You also have the luxury of placing each function in a separate file, and each file can have a different method to allocate the array.

### Static & Const Table of Function Pointers

My preference is to use a `static const` table.  Because the table is `static` and `const`, the table can be initialized at compile time.

```
struct Delegation_Entry
{
    int key;
    Function_Pointer p_function;
};
static const Delegation_Entry delegation_table[] =
{
    { 0, Do_Mode_0},
    //...
};
static const table_size =
    sizeof(delegation_table) / sizeof(delegation_table[0];

void Fuzz(const int mode)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < table_size; ++i)
    (
         if (delegation_table[i].mode == mode)
         {
             Function_Pointer p_function = delegation_table[i].p_function;
             (*p_function)();
             break;
         }
    }
    // Perform error handling if necessary
}
```

You can add more "cases" to the table without testing the code; since the code is data driven.

Comment: This could be dangerous if the code is multi-threaded or re-entrant

Comment: Using a static const delegation table is much better.

Comment: upvote for static, but I'd suggest `thread_local` instead.